# "SQL command not properly ended" - insert statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I got the below error when running the statement,

```
[sql] Failed to execute:  
INSERT INTO REPORT ( 
                   ID
                 , CI
                 , TECHNOLOGY
                 , MAJOR_VERSION
                 , MINOR_VERSION
                 , PATCH_LEVEL
                 , INSTALL_DATE
                 , INSTALLED_BY
                 , TASK ) values ( 
                                 REPORT_ID_SEQ.nextval
                               , 'host1'
                               , 'Apple card'
                               , 'N/A'
                               , 'N/A'
                               , '12233'
                               , SYSTIMESTAMP
                               , 'test@gmail.com'
                               , '' ) FROM dual
```

> Error Executing SQL Scripts: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: typo. The single quote was not missed in the original statement. I simply missed it in the post when changing the quoted hostname.

Comment: Please see [How do I ask questions
here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `from dual` at the end, you are not using any SELECT statement. 
Either you do `SELECT` or `VALUES` to insert values:

**Using SELECT**

```
INSERT INTO report 
            ( 
                    id, 
                    ci, 
                    technology, 
                    major_version, 
                    minor_version, 
                    patch_level, 
                    install_date, 
                    installed_by, 
                    task 
        ) 
SELECT     
                        report_id_seq.nextval, 
                        'host1', 
                        'Apple card', 
                        'N/A', 
                        'N/A', 
                        '12233', 
                        systimestamp, 
                        'test@gmail.com', 
                        '' 
from        dual;
```

**USING VALUES**

```
INSERT INTO report 
            ( 
                        id, 
                        ci, 
                        technology, 
                        major_version, 
                        minor_version, 
                        patch_level, 
                        install_date, 
                        installed_by, 
                        task 
            ) 
            VALUES 
            ( 
                        report_id_seq.nextval, 
                        'host1', 
                        'Apple card', 
                        'N/A', 
                        'N/A', 
                        '12233', 
                        systimestamp, 
                        'test@gmail.com', 
                        '' 
            ) ;
```

Comment: I got another issue where this insert did not work the first time. It's sequence number confliction. That issue is resolved after increasing the upper limit the seq.

Answer (score -1):

remove **from dual** and add **;** at the end, that's it.

Comment: One don't need `;` to complete a SQL statement. Absense of same will never cause SQL statement to fail, unless you are trying to run more than one statement in the IDE without delimiter `;`.